# I can't solve this integral ( $\int 3\sec^4(3x)\;dx$ ). Is there something wrong with the problem?

Tags: integration

$\displaystyle\int 3\sec^4(3x)\;dx$
I couldn't solve this integral

[image]

I've tried a lot

But it don't know how to solve it

Comment: Hint: $\sec^2 x = \ldots$ (use a Pythagorean identity).

Comment: That’s not how we hand-write the numeral 4 in English by the way

Comment: Take It easy my friend :) . I solved it with your help. Thank you all

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax and see [MathJax tutorial](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189). Please [don't use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to those who use screen readers. Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for information on writing a good question. People will be more willing to help if you [edit] your question to include an explanation of your own attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: substitutions (u- and trig).

First, use the substitution $u=3x, \text{d}u=3\text{d}x$ to make the original integral a more general form, $\displaystyle\int\sec^4 u \text{d}u$.

Notice that $\text{d}\tan u = \sec^2 u \text{d}u$ and $\sec^2 u=1+\tan^2 u$, we may write the integral as $\displaystyle\int(1+\tan^2 u) \text{d}\tan u$, which is simply $\tan u+\frac{1}{3}\tan^3 u+ C$. Substitute $u=3x$ back, we get the final answer, $\tan 3x+\frac{1}{3}\tan^3 3x+ C$.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively we can do this without substitution, a method I generally would like to avoid.

We will use the identity
$$1+\tan^2\theta\equiv\sec^2\theta$$
as well as the standard integral
$$\int\sec^2x~dx=\tan x+C$$

---

Now for the integral. We will use integration by parts, with
$$u=\sec^2x,~~~\frac{dv}{dx}=\sec^2x$$
in the standard integration by parts formula:
$$\int u\frac{dv}{dx} ~dx=uv-\int v\frac{du}{dx} ~dx$$
Note that
$$\int\sec^4x~dx=\int(\sec^2x)\sec^2x~dx=\tan x\sec^2 x-\int2\sec^2x\tan^2x~dx$$
But
$$\int\sec^2x\tan^2x~dx=\int\sec^2x(\sec^2x-1)~dx= \int\sec^4x-\sec^2x~dx$$

Hence

$$\int\sec^4x~dx=\tan x\sec^2 x-2\int\sec^4x-\sec^2x~dx=\tan x\sec^2 x-2\int\sec^4x~dx+2\int\sec^2x~dx$$
$$=\tan x\sec^2 x-2\int\sec^4x~dx+2\tan x +C$$
Rearranging gives
$$3\int\sec^4x~dx=\int3\sec^4x~dx=\tan x\sec^2 x+2\tan x +C$$

BOOM!

And we are done :)

Comment: Thank You,Can you explain where did tanxsec2x come from in the first line?

Comment: @Vahid2015 of course. Are you familiar with integration by parts?

Comment: @Vahid2015 I have edited my answer. Please tell me if you are still unclear about something.

Comment: Thank You . I've been away from education for a while. It's clear now

Comment: @Vahid2015 no problem, I'm glad to have helped you.